# How to get ID by first n letters only

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivcqp.png)

```html
<g id="test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_2">
</g>
<g id="test_model/sub1/line2_uniq_id_3">
</g>
```

i want to extract ID by first n letters in this case after **test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_** there can be any number so how i can write that check only **test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id**  because instead of _2 there can be any number.

means if i give test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_ it will take it as test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_anything
(anything can be any number)in this case it is 2

if i give test_model/sub1/line2_uniq_id_ it will take it as test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_anything
(anything can be any number)in this case it is 3

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code - in this case there are MANY examples if you search for them

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the section named [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need JavaScript.

You can get a list of all IDs starting with `test_model/sub1/line_uniq` using 
`document.querySelectorAll("[id^='test_model/sub1/line_uniq']")`

but that will only find ONE of your `<g>`s since they have different /lineX/

This one will find both

```js
function getIds() {
  let tags = document.querySelectorAll("g"); 
  let ids=[];
  for (let tag of tags) {
     ids.push(tag.id.split("_").slice(0,-1).join("_")); // use (-1) to just get the number
  }
  return ids;
}
console.log(getIds());
```

```html
<g id="test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_2">
</g>
<g id="test_model/sub1/line2_uniq_id_3">
</g>
```

Comment: actually i am fetching this id by getelementbyid(test_model/sub1/line_uniq_anything)    
like this i want

Comment: You mean `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='test_model/sub1/line_uniq']")` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a `selector` for which starts with `test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_` then here is the solution.

javascript selector

```
var abc = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_"]');
```

css selector

```
[id^="test_model/sub1/line_uniq_id_"]{
    //some css here
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan I didnot see that, Chetan might be confused with your script given in snippet I guess.

Comment: I will move it to the top of my post

Comment: yes it was not at top and in comment other users may get confused while they will check answer's for post that's why i gave @mplungjan as accepted answer now it corrected